# SharePoint2010: How to Hide 'Open Menu' option for a column in List View?

Tags: sharepoint-server, list-view

[image]

I want to hide/disable the open menu option next to a column (clicking on which gives us drop-down with 'Ascending', 'Descending' and filters) in list view. Can this is be achieved using JavaScript? If yes then how? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
div[displayname*="Title"] ~ .ms-core-menu-box,div[displayname*="Title"] ~ .ms-positionRelative
{
    display:none !important;
}
```

It will hide menu option of specified column

Comment: It didn't work for me. I can still click on the menu option next to the column name.

Comment: Have you checked that css is applied? Please verify column display name also.

Comment: Yes I have. Didn't work :(

Comment: @Korak div[displayname*="Title"] ~ .ms-core-menu-box,div[displayname*="Title"] ~ .ms-positionRelative
{
    display:none !important;
}

Comment: It is working in Mozilla, Chrome, IE 11,10,9. Please clear cookie and check it

Comment: You are working in SharePoint 2010. So please verify below arrow div class name and Open menu div class name.

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS on the page

```
.ms-vh2 {
    pointer-events: none !important;
}
```

this will disable click event

Comment: Thanks Rajesh. I will try this. But, I actually wanted to disable it for some of the columns and not all. Can I add the column name somewhere?